# Firestore Subcollections vs mongodb sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, express, mongoose

What is the difference between the two?

Subcollections store extra data inside a document as a collection and are not part of the document because they must be accessed as a separate call.

Mongodb sub documents store extra documents inside a document property as array and I'm not sure if the whole documents are retrieved in one document call.

Actually, what I'm asking is: How to achieve Subcollections in mongodb?